# Splitting a Dataset into Multiples based on a row separator

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have a dataset like the following

> [image]

with some rows containing nothing but dashes.

**Question:** Is there a way to split this dataset into multiple datasets (with the same headers) at the "dash" points?  In this particular example, there would be 3 datasets (the first one containing 2 rows, the second one containing 3 rows, and the third one containing 1 row), each with the labels "Name", "Duration", and "Notes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> "-----", "b" -> "-----"|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> "-----", "b" -> "-----"|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
   }]
```

[image]

(obviously replace with your own dataset)

We can do the following:

```
Dataset /@ 
 Select[SplitBy[Normal[ds], #a != "-----" &], 
  First[#]["a"] != "-----" &]
```

[image]

It's a bit rough, but easily extended to be a bit more graceful.

First, we change the dataset into a list of associations, using `Normal[ds]`. Then we split that list using `SplitBy` to get successive runs of rows in the dataset that don't have `"a" -> "-----"` (You may want to be a bit more specific with this predicate depending on your dataset). Then, we select only the sublists that aren't the "separator" sublists with `Select[..., First[#]["a"] != "-----"&]`. Then we simply turn the resulting lists back into `Dataset`s.